# Get raw (but formatted) email using the AWS SDK SES for PHP instead of sending it

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I was always sending standard (formatted, non-raw) emails via AWS SES by passing recipient-email / subject / html-msg-body to a SES API and SES was adding all needed information like headers, FROM EMAIL, verification data etc.

But I have a very interesting task now - to get back "raw email" just after SES prepared it, but before it was actually sent, so I could pass it to a Spam Assassin score API for evaluation.

Basically speaking, I need AWS SES to prepare "raw email" ready to be sent without actually sending it, and return it to me as a "raw email".

I did some research and my best idea for now is to send that email to my own email which will be received by SES itself and saved to S3 as a raw email following concept described here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-concepts.html

Then I could read that raw email data from S3, getting it back to application for a Spam Assassin score check, but that is probably too far from the easiest way of doing it.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.